# How can I set text of button in angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form which allows me to create a new record or update an existing one. Right now the text of the button is submit. Based on if I call the form with an optional parameter which in my case is the id of the record to edit I set my form mode as create or update. What I want is to be able to set the text displayed as either create or update but I have not found a way to change the text from my controller. I can set all field values and enable or disable the submit button but have not found a way to set the Text on button. Can this be done and if not is there a work around

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: have you tried ngModel for the label of the button and changing it based on logic in the ts file

Comment: No I did not try ngModel as I thought that that would be a more template based aproch not reactive aproach

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file.

```
 export class AppComponent  {
      buttontext="Create"
      name = 'Angular';
    }
```

In your HTML File

```
  <button>{{buttontext}}</button>
```

You can change button text accordingly.In your functions

See here-https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsxkz9

If you are looking for some other solution you have to create your own `directive`

> CustomDirective.ts file

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHidden]' })
export class HiddenDirective {

    constructor(public el: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    @Input() myHidden: boolean;

    ngOnInit(){
        // Use renderer to render the emelemt with styles
        console.log(this.myHidden)
        if(this.myHidden) {

           this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'Create');
        }

        else{
           this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'Delete');
        }
    }
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HiddenDirective } from './customdirective';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,HiddenDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      val="true";
      name = 'Angular';
    }
```

> app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)


</p>



<button [myHidden]="val"></button>
```

See this- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktf7e3

Comment: That looks to me like a template form. Can I use this also in a reactive based form with FormGroup etc ?

Comment: Well ,you should try that and let me know in comments .I guess it should work

Comment: It works somewhat but it was not what i was looking for. I was looking for a way to directly set the text of submit button via code in my controller not via a place holder for the text in HTML form

Comment: @MisterniceGuy updated my answer ,see if that  is what you are looking for